# Wait for message using socket.io and Swift 3

Tags: node.js, swift, socket.io, server, swift3

I have a server that after 10 seconds it sends out a  true. What can I do to have the iOS app wait until it receives that true value from the server? The 10 seconds isn't constant, I need the app to be able to get the Boolean no matter how long the server takes.

My app will be used to pour water until it gets to a certain height then it will notify you on your phone when it is done.

UPDATE (More Info):

Link to guide I am following: http://www.appcoda.com/socket-io-chat-app/

```
func getChatMessage(completionHandler: (messageInfo: [String: AnyObject]) -> Void) {
    socket.on("newChatMessage") { (dataArray, socketAck) -> Void in
        var messageDictionary = [String: AnyObject]()
        messageDictionary["nickname"] = dataArray[0] as! String
        messageDictionary["message"] = dataArray[1] as! String
        messageDictionary["date"] = dataArray[2] as! String

        completionHandler(messageInfo: messageDictionary)
    }
}


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.getChatMessage { (messageInfo) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.chatMessages.append(messageInfo)
            self.tblChat.reloadData()
            //                self.scrollToBottom()
        })
    }
}
```

I want to do something very similar to this which is constantly getting messages from the server and loading them into the view. This code however doesn't work with Swift 3/iOS 10, and I can't find any documentation on how to update it. I tried simply putting it into my code and then using the recommended fixes to try and get it to work but it didn't.

In the end my server will be hosted on a Pi Zero and I will need to receive a message from the Pi, via the server, that the water has reached the appropriate level. 
Thanks

Comment: you could run a timer that runs every 1 second (or every 0.1 seconds or whatever) and send the alert and end the timer if true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Result:

[image]

## iOS Source Code:

Once you are connected to the server.

```
socket.on("connect") { data, ack in
  self.socket.emit("get-notified-water", "")
}
```

You tell the server that you want to get notified about the water tank level.

```
self.socket.emit("get-notified-water", "")
```

And then you listen the notification here:

```
socket.on("notification-water") { data in
  let levelTank = data.0.first as! Int
  self.updateViewWithLevelTank(levelTank)
}
```

**NOTE:** Intentionally I didn't include `updateViewWithLevelTank` function implementation since I want you to be focus on the important part that is connecting with the server and being notified with the water tank level, besides I don't think it is complicated to mimic the UIView animation.

---

```
import UIKit
import SocketIO

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var tankView: UIView!
  let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:5000")!)

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    socket.on("connect") { data, ack in
      self.socket.emit("get-notified-water", "")
    }
    
    socket.on("notification-water") { data in
      let levelTank = data.0.first as! Int
      self.updateViewWithLevelTank(levelTank)
    }
    
    socket.connect()
  }

}
```

---

## Server Source code:

`setInterval` will call **the anonymous function** until `levelTank` is 100.

In which the **the anonymous function**, notifies the client (iOS socket) the `levelTank` every time is called.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var port = 5000;

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

  socket.on('get-notified-water', function(data) {
    var levelTank = 0;
    var intervalTime = 500;

    var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
      levelTank += 10
      socket.emit('notification-water', levelTank);

      if (levelTank === 100) {
        clearInterval(intervalId)
      }
    }, intervalTime);
  });

});

http.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at %s port', port);
});
```

So let me know if this works for your case or you need any more clarification of my example, probably I've missed something who knows? ;)